# Copy DataGridViewColumnHeaderCell obj

Tags: c#, winforms, ado.net

I don't think DataGridViewColumnHeaderCell implements IClonable so I was thinking of using the Xml.Serialization to copy this object to avoid an unwanted reference. What do you think? Overkill?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested this and the clone never copied the object for some unknown reason. I had to copy each row's properties.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't to do it, `DataGridViewColumnHeaderCell` implements the [`IClonable.Clone()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumnheadercell.clone.aspx) method.

```
object clonedObject = myDataGridViewColumnHeaderCell.Clone();
```

**EDIT:**

> but it doesn't copy the data. And ColumnIndex is a readonly property
>   which is one of 2 properties I'm interested in preserving.

Sincerly I've never used it on `DataGridViewColumnHeaderCell`, but it should work.
Howerever If you just need to preserve two properties you can create your *customized Clone method*:

```
public static class Utilities{
    public static object CloneObject(this DataGridViewColumnHeaderCell myObj){
         DataGridViewColumnHeaderCell clonedObject = new DataGridViewColumnHeaderCell();

         //here clone your properties
         clonedObject.ColumnIndex = myObj.ColumnIndex;              

         return clonedObject;
    }
}
```

Then:

```
object clonedObject = myDataGridViewColumnHeaderCell.CloneObject();
```

**PS:** In the case of `ColumnIndex` you just need to assign it to the new object because it's of type int which is a struct and you don't pass a reference.

Comment: but it doesn't copy the data. And ColumnIndex is a readonly property which is one of 2 properties I'm interested in preserving.

Comment: Thanks I'll try again this evening and thank you for your insight.